# Messenger: How to wait for messages to be processed?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I have an Xamarin.Android Application using MVVMLight messenger.

The application is also using a background service.

Both the application and the service register to a StopApplicationAndServiceMessage message:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<StopApplicationAndServiceMessage>(...)
```

They each pass a custom method to se second parameter.

The application menu has an option to quit the application that posts the **StopApplicationAndServiceMessage** message.

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new StopApplicationAndServiceMessage(reason));
```

When processing the message in the application, is there a way to wait for/ensure that the message has been processed by the background service?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter set in Register method is used to ensure the message received .

```
Messenger.Default.Register<StopApplicationAndServiceMessage>(
  this,
  message =>
  {
     // message processed here .
  });
```

Comment: The action to process the message is not the same for both registrar

Comment: Create a global static int variable in MainActivity , while every  registrar  receiving message , increase the variable in the callback , you can monitor the value of variable to see  if it equals to the amount of registrars .